# Elements overlapping in design view in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, layout, designview

I have a long job application form, about 7000px in length, with several tables that contain form inputs (textboxes, radio buttons, etc.). Each table is nested in its own div (applicant info, work history, education etc.). I intend to make the sections collapsible when complete, however design view started overlapping the elements after about 5000px, making it hard to judge the layout. At runtime no overlap occurs. I realize design view is not an exact browser representation, but this overlapping seems exceptionally quirky. I am only using relative positioning and minimal styling at this point. I tried setting the height of the content to a large number to no effect. Does anyone know if this is a bug with VS or if there is some setting that will prevent it, I couldn't find any. It seems to only happen when the content of the page runs long.  Thanks.